# Linear differential equation to solve.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Good evening everyone ,

Could you please explain to me how we solve the following linear differential equation with constant coefficients : $ (E) \ \ y^{(n)} - y = e^{ \alpha x} $ with $ \alpha $ an $n$- root of unity ?
The solutions of this equation is put in the form: $ y = y_G + y_P $ with : $ y_G $ general solution of the equation $ y^{(n)} - y = 0 $ is of the form: $ y_{G} (x) = \displaystyle \sum_{ i = 0}^{ n-1 } \lambda_{i} e^{ \mu^{i} x} $ with $ \mu $ is an $ n $ th root of unity and $ \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R} $ for all $ i = 0, 1, \dots , n-1 $. In contrast, I do not know how to find $ y_{P} $ : particular solution of the equation $ (E) $.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bf hint:$ make a change of variable $y = ve^{\alpha x}.$ find and solve the differential equations satisfied by $v.$

$\bf edit:$

you only need the coefficient of $v'.$ just to be specific, let us take $n = 3.$ then $$y' = (v' + \alpha v)e^{\alpha x}, y'' = (v'' + 2 \alpha v' + \alpha^2 v)e^{\alpha x}, y''' = (v''' + 3 \alpha v'' + 3 \alpha^2 v' + \alpha^3 v)e^{\alpha x}$$ we need to solve $$e^{\alpha x} = y''' - y = e^{\alpha x}\left(v''' + 3 \alpha v'' + 3 \alpha^2 v' + \alpha^3 v - v \right)$$ that is $$v''' + 3 \alpha v'' + 3 \alpha^2 v'  = 1$$ this has a particular solution $$v = \frac 1{3\alpha^2}x, $$

$$  y = \frac 1{3\alpha^2}xe^{\alpha x} \text{ is a particular solution of  } y''' - y = e^{\alpha x} \text{ where $\alpha$ is a cube root of $1.$ }   $$

Comment: $ v=v(x) $, right ?

Comment: @Bryan261,yes. $v$ is a function of $x.$

Comment: Thank you. This is what i obtain finally :  if : $ y(x) = v(x) e^{ \alpha x } $, then : $ y^{(n)} (x) = \displaystyle \sum_{ k=0}^{n} C_{n}^{k} \alpha^k v^{(n-k)} $. So : $ y^{(n)} - y = e^{ \alpha x } $ involves : $ ( \displaystyle \sum_{ k=0}^{n} C_{n}^{k} \alpha^k v^{(n-k)} - v(x) ) e^{ \alpha x } = e^{ \alpha x } $

Comment: @Bryan261, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Try $y_P=A x e^{\alpha x}$ for some undetermined coefficient $A$. Plug this into your differential equation and find $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer , however, the particular solution : $ y_P (x) = Ax e^{ \alpha x} $ is valid only for quadratic equations of type: $ a_2 y '' + a_1 y ' + a_0 y = e^{ \alpha x} $ and not for equations of the nth degree of type : $ \displaystyle \sum_{ k = 0 }^{n} a_k  y^{ (k)} = e^{ \alpha x} $, right?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It is a trial solution. It could be valid for any linear DE with constant coefficients if it works. A typical way for this kind of problem, when the right hand side is part of the $y_C$, is to multiply the trial solution by $x$.

Comment: If we set $ y (x) = A x e^{ \alpha x} $ , I get by recurrence the following thing : $ y^{ (n)} (x) = A (n \alpha^{ n-1 } +  \alpha^n x) e^{ \alpha x} $ .
And therefore , $ y^{ (n)} - y = e^{\alpha x} $ involves: $ A (n \alpha^{ n- 1} + ( \alpha^n - 1) x ) e^{\alpha x } = e^{ \alpha x} $. This is ultimately incompatible I think.

Comment: Remember $\alpha^n=1$?

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you very much.  :-)